# Click on Run tests via MTM(Microsoft Test Manager) stopped working after update the OS to windows 10

Tags: tfs, windows-10, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I use Microsoft Test Manager - Desktop Application to run tests. In the past - Clicking on Run button Causes that a new window appear and the tests start work.

Recently I updated OS to Windows 10 and after updating the OS, Click of Run button is not responding.

[image: MTM run test problem]

Anyone have any idea what can do the cause?

Thanks

Comment: What version of MTM? For what it's worth, MTM has been deprecated for **years**. You should be looking for a way to migrate from MTM to using the test hub.

Comment: What's your TFS and MTM version?

Comment: -The TFS version is 2017.   -The MTM version is 11.0.50727.1(i think it's 2012)

Answer (score 0):

First to say, we strongly recommend you use **Azure Test Plans** or the Test hub in TFS (a fully featured Test management solution) over Microsoft Test Manager for all your test management requirements.

**There will be no new versions of Microsoft Test Manager**. Microsoft Test Manager 2017 (which shipped with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017) is the last version.

Please kindly take a look at our official tutorial-- [Guidance on Microsoft Test Manager usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/mtm/guidance-mtm-usage?view=azure-devops-2019)

This link will help you understand why Azure Test Plans or the Test hub in TFS is a more comprehensive solution for manual testing compared to Microsoft Test Manager.

If you insist on using old MTM(Microsoft Test Manager) with your TFS. Please try to install the latest version Microsoft Test Manager 2017 (which shipped with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017). Definitely work with windows10, this may do the trick.